# Prefered method of populating a std::vector of classes with its first entry

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

In reviewing a large software project I came a cross two ways of doing essentially the same thing, pushing an initial entry on a std::vector

consider a class like Foo

```
class Foo
{
   public:

    Foo(int param){
      m_param = param;
    }

    setParam(int param){
      m_param = param;
    }
  private:
    int m_param;
}
```

Is there a preferred method between the following considering whatever applicable metrics.... speed, stability, etc.

```
Foo bar;
int val = 5;
bar.setParam(val);
std::vector<Foo> fooVec(1, bar);
```

Versus

```
int val = 5;
std::vector<Foo> fooVec;
fooVec.push_back(Foo(val));
```

Comment: The best way would be to follow a convention. If the first inserted value is somehow special, then I'd opt for the constructor. If not, then I'd opt for push_back.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a preferred method between the following considering whatever applicable metrics.... speed, stability, etc.

<strike>It can be argued that</strike> *Without doubt* this is poor style:

```
auto test1()
{
    Foo bar;               // redundant default construction
    int val = 5;           // redundant load
    bar.setParam(val);     // only now setting the value
    std::vector<Foo> fooVec(1, bar);  // redundant copy
    return fooVec;
}
```

and that this is good style:

```
auto test2()
{
    return std::vector<Foo>(1, Foo(5));
}
```

> What about performance, we all care about that, right?

But what does it mean in reality? once you've enabled optimisations?...

```
__Z5test1v:                             ## @_Z5test1v
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:                                ## %_ZNSt3__16vectorI3FooNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEC2EmRKS1_.exit1
    pushq   %rbx
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -16
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    movq    $0, 16(%rbx)
    movq    $0, 8(%rbx)
    movq    $0, (%rbx)
    movl    $4, %edi
    callq   __Znwm
    movq    %rax, (%rbx)
    leaq    4(%rax), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rbx)
    movl    $5, (%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 8(%rbx)
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    popq    %rbx
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  __Z5test2v
    .align  4, 0x90
__Z5test2v:                             ## @_Z5test2v
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:                                ## %_ZNSt3__16vectorI3FooNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEC2EmRKS1_.exit1
    pushq   %rbx
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -16
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    movq    $0, 16(%rbx)
    movq    $0, 8(%rbx)
    movq    $0, (%rbx)
    movl    $4, %edi
    callq   __Znwm
    movq    %rax, (%rbx)
    leaq    4(%rax), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rbx)
    movl    $5, (%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 8(%rbx)
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    popq    %rbx
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

Absolutely no difference whatsoever. The generated machine code is exactly the same in this case.

Comment: But still, you would like to generate that same code in style, wouldn't you?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin absolutely!

Comment: Thanks for the response... I would have like to see a test3 that was a vector declaration followed by a push_back.

Comment: @dafew that's pushing it too far on clang and gcc. They produce horrible code when you do that. you can easily check it here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/#

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have a fairly specific reason to use one of these, like needing to support an older (pre-C++11) compiler, I'd just use:

```
std::vector<Foo> fooVec { 5 }; // or fooVec { foo(5) };, if you really prefer
```

This is pretty much guaranteed to be as fast, stable, etc. as any of the others (and may be a tad faster, depending...)

Comment: That opens a can of worms. What is 5? is it the size of the vector or an argument to the constructor? I can't tell without going through the docs, and I am not the worst developer out there.

Comment: @SergeyA: I can't agree. If you don't know this, then you simply don't know the language, and complaining about it is like complaining that French people are wrong when they use "pain" to mean "bread" instead of "hurts".

Comment: It is funny, but the meaning of `{5}` depends on the definition of `Foo`. If `Foo` can be constructred from `int`, than this creates a vector of size 1. Otherwise, a vector of size 5.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: those both do exactly what any reasonable person would expect: the first creates an array of one element with a value of 5. The second creates a vector of two elements, both with values of 5. This is not exactly new, nor should it surprise anybody (been standard since 2011, and the plan to standardize it was well known for years before that).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Cannot understand what _those both_ refer to.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: `{5}` and `{5, 5}`. (Rereading...yeah, still looks like you must be working really hard to misunderstand the obvious throughout the entire thread in a vain attempt at justifying a ridiculous down-vote).

Comment: @JerryCoffin My point is that `{5}` (one same syntax) does two different things here depending on the definition of `Foo`. Not sure why you refer to `{5, 5}`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: I responded about `{5, 5}` because **you** posted "now try it with `{ 5, 5 }`", of course. As far as what happens with some completely different type: yes, if you enter completely different code involving completely different types, you get different results. Now read the question and try to find any reference to a type that can't be initialized from the value being passed. It's not there. So yes, you're attempting to justify a down-vote because it answers the question that was asked, rather than something else entirely that the OP doesn't ask or apparently care about. Wow!

Comment: @JerryCoffin That was not an accurate comment and long been replaced with a new one. Yet, you keep banging about the removed comment whilst ignoring the new one with an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108310/discussion-between-jerry-coffin-and-maxim-egorushkin).

Comment: The problem is until you inspect the definition of `Foo`, the meaning of `std::vector<Foo> v{5};` is impossible to determine.  It is either a vector of 5 default-constructed `Foo`s, or one `Foo` constructed from `5`.  This makes that line of code difficult to understand, because you have to be aware of what set of things `Foo` can be constructed from to understand it.  In comparison, `std::vector<Foo> v{Foo(5)};` is far more clear.  This problem is not exactly new, it has been widely known as a really annoying issue since shortly after the standard was published in 2011.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, I realize there are circumstances under which this could do something different. And yes, if the question had been something about: "is this the best-designed part of C++11", the answer would be a clear "No". **But**, that's not what he asked about.